# Domain URL is not behaving like the API Gateway URL

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

In my API Controller in C#, I have the following code fragment:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetAll()
    {
        return "GET";
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string GetSingle(int id)
    {
        return $"GET /{id}";
    }
```

Everything is going well until I mapped my API Gateway to a Domain in AWS.

API Gateway Behavior (which I **expect** from API Gateway too):

1. https://asd123456.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/ **returns**

```
GET
```

2. https://asd123456.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/1 **returns**

```
GET /1
```

Above is what I expect the Domain URL behavior to be, but the behavior I get from Domain URL is:

1. https://domainurl.com/path/ **returns**

```
GET /0
```

This is not what I expect, I only expect **GET** and this also indicates that **GetAll()** function isn't being called at all.

2. https://domainurl.com/path/1 **returns**

```
GET /1
```

On AWS CDK Typescript, the mapped my API Gateway to the Domain Name like this:

```
new aws_apigateway.CfnBasePathMapping(this.scope, this.id+'BasePathMapping', {
    basePath: this.basePath,
    domainName: this.domainName,
    restApiId: this._restApi.restApiId,
    stage: this.restApi.deploymentStage.stageName,
});
```

Additonal Info: Everything else working fine, it's just that the **GetAll()** isn't working at all, and I couldn't figure the problem why is it working in the API Gateway, but not in the Custom Domain Name/URL.

I have a fix on this by modifying the **GetSingle()** function to check if the value of **id** is less than or equal to 0, but I don't think that is the best solution for this. It is a temporary solution, and I feel like someone in the community have encountered or may have a better solution for this one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  This is strange, I can't say I've seen it before nor can I think of anything that can provide a default value of 0... is there any way you can `GET /0` locally as well or does this only happen with the custom domain? Have you changed anything in the API gateway integration settings? Can you please make sure you're using something like `curl` to make your requests so they're repeatable, and add the full command output for the gateway as well as the custom domain for both requests to the question?